# Ubuntu 18 WiFi adapater not found in HP laptop

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-one, adapter

I just installed Ubuntu 18 my Laptop and I am facing issue with WiFi adapater not found  and I approached lot of blogs but still not resolved my issue.

I approached below link WiFi works fine after installing but if I restarting my system then it issue again repeating with WiFi adapater not found.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/

Please provide the solution for this issue

Comment: What is the name of your wifi adapter ?

Comment: Adapater Name : `rtl8723de`

Answer (score 1):

For the rtl8723de follow these instructions https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de

The commands given there, for installation, are:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 5.0-up
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```

List of all Realtek Wi-Fi supported https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new